# "Kindergarten" old fashioned?

Tags: word-usage

Is "kindergarten" an old fashioned word nowadays? I see it used in many kindergartens' websites, how (un)popular is it?

Comment: To me, it was never anything *but* an old-fashioned borrowing from German for at least the past 50 years. During which time I doubt if I've actually *used* the word myself even half-a-dozen times.

Comment: I can only attest to my personal experience, but it's still in common use here in NYC.

Comment: Still a perfectly valid word in the US.  Some education districts make a distinction between "kindergarten" and, eg, "pre-school", though what that distinction is is not clear to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's not the definition of "old fashioned" in the comparative sense as in the question.

Comment: @Kris: I've absolutely no idea what you mean. But it's important to note that the word is [at least three times as common in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kindergarten&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckindergarten%3B%2Cc0) as it is in [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kindergarten&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckindergarten%3B%2Cc0). And I'd guess most of the recent BrE upsurge in that second link are misclassified AmE usages anyway.

Comment: "I see it used in many kindergartens' websites, how popular is it". Talk about answering your own question right there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just out of curiosity, what do you call it in the UK if you don't call it kindergarten?

Comment: @Nicole: British kids start "real" school at 5. Until then, they're mostly looked after by (grand)parents or childminders. They often go to "preschool" for a few months (perhaps not *every* day) just to get used to the social context of being herded in with many others.

Comment: "Mostly", @FumbleFingers? I'd say most parents work nowadays, and many live far from grandparents. I don't know figures, but I think most preschool kids to to nursery these days; which is the answer to @Nicole's question.

Comment: @Martin: [*Just over 200,000 children under three now attend a day nursery. It comfortably outstrips all other forms of non-family care for under-threes*](http://www.theguardian.com/education/2004/jul/08/schools.uk). Although not explicitly stated, I think it's a racing certainty more than 200,000 fall into the "family care" category.

Comment: Fascinating. You live and learn. Specifically, in my case, you live in London; things may be different in other parts of the country (or even in other parts of London, come to think of it). On the other hand, there are school nurseries as well as private nurseries, and I suspect that many more kids go to those. Also they are probably closer to the American kindergarten.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would think the numbers attending pre-school/day nursery (or whatever you care to call it) are vastly higher, in the case of 3 and 4-year olds. Remember that from April 1 this year all of that group will be entitled to 15 hours a week free of charge. (Or more accurately, at the expense of you and me the taxpayer).130,000 2-yr olds will have the same from September, rising to 260,000 by September 2016.

Comment: So we are on sociology-se, having long digressed off English language, carried by the question?

Comment: @FumbleFingers "**1** (In Britain and Australia) an establishment where children below the age of compulsory education play and learn; a nursery school. **1.1** (In North America) a class or school that prepares children, usually five- or six-year-olds, for the first year of formal education." ODO http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kindergarten

Comment: This question is not much about the English language. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

At least in the northeast US, *kindergarten* is still routinely used to refer to the year before 1st grade. It generally is intended for 5 year olds. There is usually a cutoff date for fall entry (such as 5 by the following December 31) comparable to the 1st grade cutoff (such as 6 by December 31).

Most public schools in this area, and many private schools, offer kindergarten as a standard (but not compulsory) part of their curriculum.

The terms *pre-K*, *pre-school* and *nursery school* tend to be reserved for the years before kindergarten.

Comment: I think this is true in the rest of the US as well.

Comment: So, it seems *kindergarten* is a standard term in the US, but not in the UK.  For all we know, Joanna is in Australia or somewhere.  Maybe when she comes back she can clarify her question.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., schools are typically divided into elementary schools (1st-5th grade), middle or junior high schools (6th-8th grade), and high schools (9th-12th grade). However, it's not uncommon to find [K-8 schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-8_school), where students attend from kindergarten to eighth grade. In these schools, "kindergarten" is considered a grade just like second grade or fifth grade, so it's used quite often. In contrast, "preschool" or "pre-K" would be what a child would attend  before beginning at the K-8 school.

Answer (score 0):

Google N-grams [suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kindergarten%2Cpreschool%2C%20nursery%20school&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckindergarten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreschool%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnursery%20school%3B%2Cc0) the word is still in common use, though recently it's been overtaken slightly by "pre-school". By contrast, the term "nursery school" is definitely on the decline:

[image: Google nGram comparing "kindergarten", "preschool", and "nursery school"]

Comment: "Preschool (also, pre-school)" is also a generic adjective, so it would naturally occur more widely. That needs to be factored in.

Comment: Pre-school education
Kindergarten, play school and nursery school.


Pre-school education embraces all formal and informal education before the age of six (when compulsory schooling starts). It includes tots and toddler programmes, play school, nursery school (collectively known as pre-kindergarten) and kindergarten.https://www.justlanded.com/english/United-States/USA-Guide/Education/Pre-school-education

Comment: @Kris I know nGrams permits some fancy searching syntax that allows one to distinguish between parts of speech, but I'm not familiar enough with it to distinguish word classes in this case. If you are, please feel free to edit the URL in my question and the attendant graph. I may make another attempt later in the day if I get time.

Comment: Even that may be of limited use. Preschool is not a one-to-one substitute for kindergarten anyway.

Comment: @Kris, no, but at least one sense of it *is* used as a direct synonym for kindergarten. Some schools around here which had called themselves "kindergartens" for years have recently switched their name/branding to "preschool", without any changes to the curriculum or day-to-day operations. The challenge is distinguishing the contexts where the words are used synonymously be not.

Comment: When you answer "around here" maybe also say where you are...

Comment: @GEdgar See [my earlier comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229191/kindergarten-old-fashioned#comment489562_229191).